# Jacobian of decoder in VAE

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, gradient, keras-layer

I am new to both ML and this forum, so please be kind.

What I would like to compute is the jacobian of the decoder part of the VAE w.r.t. the latent vectors. I have found the jacobian_batch function in tensorflow.python.ops.parallel_for.gradients that in principle could do the job for me. However, I could not get this function to work. 
More specifically, I tried:

```
xin = tf.constant(np.array(latent_vector[2]),dtype=tf.float32)
f_of_xin = tf.constant(decoder.predict(tf.Session().run(xin), batch_size = 1000000, verbose=1),dtype=tf.float32) 
jac = batch_jacobian(f_of_xin,xin)
```

Which does not work (returns None shape), while:

```
f_of_xin = tf.sin(tf.sin(xin))
jac = batch_jacobian(f_of_xin,xin)
```

works (returns a 3x3 matrix (# of input & output dim = 3) with sensible numbers). 
I tried:

```
f_of_xin = tf.sin(tf.sin(tf.constant(tf.Session().run(xin))))
```

as well, in which case the jacobian_batch function does not work anymore (which means that it returns a None shape). I guess it has to do with the data conversion, but I don't know how to feed a tf structure to the model.predict function. By the way, my model here (decoder) is just a simple neural network with 1 hidden layer. Could you help me?

Kind regards,

Melissa